# Automating commit amend procedure

Tags: git, zsh, git-amend

I am finding myself annoyed at having to run the full procedure to amend commits in git and I was wondering which was the best way of automate them.
So, instead of doing this:

```
$> git add .
$> git commit --amend
$> git push -f
```

I'd love to do this

```
$> amend_commit
```

Is shell scripting the only way to do it? I am using ZSH.

Thank you all.

Comment: why would you force-push amended commits? That sounds quite bad.

Comment: Because I never work on master or shared branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is a pretty bad idea to automate a forced push, as it rewrites the history and everyone else working with the same repository will hate you, you can also define a git alias instead of a shell alias like

```
git config alias.amend '!git add . && git commit --amend && git push -f'
```

or if you don't want to edit the commit message, then

```
git config alias.amend '!git add . && git commit --amend -C HEAD && git push -f'
```

and then you can do `git amend` to use it.

Comment: Thanks! This would work perfectly! Luckily my company's workflow does not involve working shared branches so I can force push as much as I want without being hated! :)

Comment: Then you are probably fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an alias. This should work:

```
alias amend_commit="git add . && git commit --amend && git push -f"
```

Comment: Something this complicated should be a function instead of an alias.

Answer (score 0):

You can cut out one of the steps by using the `-a` flag to `git commit` to auto-add any changes:

```
git commit -a --amend
git push -f
```

As another user has already commented, it seems dangerous to fold an automatic force-push into this workflow.

Amending an already pushed branch is advised against. I'd say it is something you should do relatively infrequently, unless you are using a workflow that allows for mutable feature branches (for rebasing, etc).